# How to pass an URL via Zend parms?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm trying to pass an URL (or just a local file path) via the Zend setPara(). Unfortunately the router interprets this as several params.

```
$redirector = $this->_helper->getHelper('Redirector');
$redirector->gotoSimple('download', null, null, array('TEMP_FILE' => '/srv/www/htdocs/tmp/output.pdf'));
```

Apache shows error 404. The downloadAction() isn't called. So maybe there is another way to pass an entire URL from one action to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$params = array('param1' => $param1, 'param2' => $param2);
$this->_helper->redirector('download', 'yourcontroller', 'yourmodule', $params);
```

if you dont have a module ..leave empty for that

Another simple way

```
$this->redirect('/module/controller/download/param1/value/param2/value2');
```

update
use `urlencode` for params

```
$this->redirect('/module/controller/download/param1/'.urlencode(value).'/param2/'.urle
ncode(value2).');
```

and while accessing use `urldecode(value);`

Comment: As I mentioned above one of my params is an URL. So I'm getting the 404 error. The result of my example shows as:
localhost/offer/report/download/TEMP_FILE/%2Fsrv%2Fwww%2Fhtdocs%2Ftmp%2Foutput.pdf

Comment: then try the first method